# Where to put wrapper scripts in Buildr?

Tags: scala, installation, wrapper, buildr

I'm developing a set of command line tools in Scala, using Apache Buildr as my build system. I'd like to include a wrapper script for each tool. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
scala myclass $@
```

These scripts should be installed alongside my jar when I type `buildr install`. Is there a special directory Buildr recognizes for wrapper scripts like this? If not, how can I make Buildr install the scripts? I've tried putting the scripts in src/main/resources, but this packages them inside the jar, which is not what I want.

Comment: `buildr install` copies packages into the local Maven repository.  Do you really want to copy your scripts individually into the Maven repository?  It's more typical to create a zip/tgz distribution file containing a `bin` directory with those files.  In that case, you `package(:zip).path('bin').include _('src/bin')`

Comment: I would like people downloading my package as a dependency (like Buildr does with Scala) to have access to these wrapper scripts, rather than having to write their own. I suppose it's reasonable to distribute a separate zip or tgz from the Maven package, but it seems strange to me.

Comment: I rather used Alex's approach in the past.

I would package with a tgz and maybe enhance buildr install to unpack the files on installation ?

Answer (score 0):

As commented, there are ways to make this happen by creating a separate packaging to encompass the scripts and the tool. Here is an [example](https://github.com/atoulme/logBot/blob/master/Buildfile) that bundles a jar and a set of scripts to run the jar with parameters.